# Speech recognition not working

Tags: c#, wpf, speech-recognition

I am developing a WPF application which uses speech recognition. The events does not fire up when the grammar words are spoken. Secondly, I am not sure whether the engine starts up on not. How to check that?  Following is the code.

```
namespace Summerproject_trial
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
       private SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = 
                                    new SpeechRecognitionEngine();           

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Choices mychoices = new Choices();
            mychoices.Add(new string[] {"Ok", "Test", "Hello"});
            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Append(mychoices);
            Grammar mygrammar = new Grammar(gb);
            recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(mygrammar);          

            recEngine.SpeechRecognized += 
                               new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>
                                              (recEngine_SpeechRecognized);

            recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();              
        }

        void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender,
                                        SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You said: " + e.Result.Text);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it exactly as in the example on the [SpeechRecognitionEngine MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx)?

Comment: yes, exactly the same way. I think the code reflects it.

Comment: "I think the code reflects it". Doesn't look like. No idea if it's important, but the MSDN sample creates the `SpeechRecognitionEngine` with a CultureInfo, you don't. Then it loads a `DictationGrammar`. You don't. That's why I asked for *exactly*.

Comment: I have seen some video tutorials and in them nowhere did it use Dictation grammar or CultureInfo.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to start listening to input.

Try this in the end of your constructor.

```
recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

Comment: which constructor..below the private recognition engine line?

Comment: This `public MainWindow()` is the constructor, so after this line: `recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()`

Comment: do I need some additional libraries or sdk?

Comment: `System.Speech.dll` should be enough, why, are you getting errors?

Comment: though the debugger does not show any errors, but still the event does not fires up.

Comment: did you check if your microphone actually works and is assigned as default input device?

Comment: I have  mobile earphones.Can it be used as input device. I doubt that it has not been assigned as input device(default). How can I assign it as default device. secondly, if I don't run the program and just use the speech recognition as in starting it from Start->Speech recognition, in that case it works fine for commands like Start(opens start menu), Close(closes window) etc.But even if that is working, then why not with my application source code.

Answer (score 0):

@Anri's answer is needed, but you *also* need to create the SpeechRecognitionEngine with a CultureInfo.  (You can create a SpeechRecognitionEngine without a CultureInfo, but then you need to set the recognizer language explicitly.)

Also:  Mobile earphones (by which I assume you mean some sort of Bluetooth headset) will typically NOT work with System.Speech.  The SR engine used in the desktop SR engine requires higher quality audio input than it can get from Bluetooth.

So, complete code that should work:

```
   private SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = 
                                new SpeechRecognitionEngine("en-US");           

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Choices mychoices = new Choices();
        mychoices.Add(new string[] {"Ok", "Test", "Hello"});
        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Append(mychoices);
        Grammar mygrammar = new Grammar(gb);
        recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(mygrammar);          

        recEngine.SpeechRecognized += 
                           new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>
                                          (recEngine_SpeechRecognized);

        recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }
```